# Unpivot table with two rows as column headers

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010, excel-2010, powerquery, unpivot

I know how to unpivot an Excel table with one row as column header using power query. But recently I had a need to unpivot with 2 rows as column header. For example if we have this:

```
    b1  b1  b2  b2  b2
    c1  c2  c1  c2  c3
a1   1   4   7   3   4
a2   5   8   9   8   6
a3   3   6   9   6   2
```

a=row heading and b & c=column headings

and we want this:

```
a1  b1  c1  1
a1  b1  c2  4
a1  b2  c1  7
a1  b2  c2  3
a1  b2  c3  4
a2  b1  c1  5
a2  b1  c2  8
a2  b2  c1  9
a2  b2  c2  8
a2  b2  c3  6
a3  b1  c1  3
etc.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What do you want the solution in, SQL, Access, Excel or Power Query? Remove the tags for the others and just leave the environment you want the solution in there. Also, please take the time to post the data in a consumable format (not an image). Tabular formatted `text` will likely work fine, or DDL and DML statements if you're actually looking for a SQL Server solution.

Comment: If I have only one column header (b or c) then I can use power query and it is simple to unpivot. I do not mind any choice of technology from those mentioned

Comment: Now we just need to know what language you want the solution in.

Comment: I do not mind any choice of technology from those mentioned

Comment: That dosen't help us help you though, @non

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, you can do this by

1. Transposing the table and promoting headers to get:

```
_   _1  a1  a2  a3
b1  c1  1   5   3
b1  c2  4   8   6
b2  c1  7   9   9
b2  c2  3   8   6
b2  c3  4   6   2
```

2. Then you can unpivot the `a` columns.

```
    _1  Atr Value
b1  c1  a1  1
b1  c1  a2  5
b1  c1  a3  3
b1  c2  a1  4
b1  c2  a2  8
b1  c2  a3  6
b2  c1  a1  7
b2  c1  a2  9
b2  c1  a3  9
b2  c2  a1  3
b2  c2  a2  8
b2  c2  a3  6
b2  c3  a1  4
b2  c3  a2  6
b2  c3  a3  2
```

3. Rearrange, sort, and rename columns as desired.